# Why is the width of element different outside a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  padding: 0 50px;
  
  background-color: grey;
}

a{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <p>Other content</p>
  <a>Test Button</a>
</div>

 <a>Test Button</a>
```

As you can see, the style of the two anchor tags **are not the same**. Inside the flex container, the link has the desired width and line-height, but outside it **only changes its background color**. I guess that has something to do with the container, but I can't tell what. **Why is that happening?**

Comment: "flex items" are different from "inline elements". To make the latter behave the same, add display: inlne-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> The display value of a flex item **is blockified**: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent.

Your link is an inline element but inside a flexbox container it becomes a flex item and behave differently.

Many properties can do the same like for example using `float`

```css
a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a>Test Button</a>
<hr>
<a style="float:left">Test Button</a>
```

`width` and `line-height` don't behave the same with inline element or "block-like" elements which explain the difference.

> 10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced elements
>
> The 'width' property does not apply <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-width)</sup>

and

> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)</sup>

So the width doesn't apply and the line-height won't change the height of the element but is only considered to calculate the line box height.

The trivial fix is to use `inline-block`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <p>Other content</p>
  <a>Test Button</a>
</div>

<a>Test Button</a>
```